# tar: kill the error message: 'tar: Removing leading `/' from member names'

Tags: tar, stderr

I run this from a cronjob:

```
tar -czvf /var/backups/svn.tgz /var/svn/*
```

That generates this on stderr:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

I would like to avoid this because it is not a real error (for me!).
I want on stderr only things that I should worry about?

How can I kill that message?

I have the feeling that it is a matter of using the tar -C option but I am not sure and I don't know how.

Thanks for the help,
Dan

Comment: See also [tar: Removing leading \`/' from member names](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59243)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your options:

```
-P, --absolute-names : don't strip leading `/'s from file names
```

or

```
-C /
```

... and a relative path for things to go into the tar, like so:

```
tar -C / -czvf /var/backups/svn.tgz var/svn/*
```

Comment: I don't want -P. I want -C but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I have found it out: tar -czvf /var/backups/svn.tgz -C / var/svn/

Comment: Borrowing a warning regarding -P from another thread:
Archives with absolute locations are a security risk. Attackers could use such archives to trick users into installing files in critical system locations.

Comment: Archives with absolute locations are a security risk. Attackers could use such archives to trick users into installing files in critical system locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
# ( tar czvf tar.file /path 2>&1 ) >log.file
```

The message will be written to log.file